# IAM credentials not found on AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I'm trying to automate a db backup upload to s3 on an ubuntu machine. I have the db backup generating correctly, but when I try to upload to s3 I get the following error:

```
 A client error (InvalidAccessKeyId) occurred when calling the PutObject 
operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

I used the command line aws configure command to configure my credentials, then opened the ~/.aws/config file and made sure it was correct. I also ran

```
aws configure list
```

and received the following:

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
    ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
   access_key     ****************B6YQ      config_file    ~/.aws/config
   secret_key     ****************Vstu      config_file    ~/.aws/config
   region               cn-north-1      config_file    ~/.aws/config
```

When that didn't work I tried regenerating new credentials for both the root user and the IAM user, but that still didn't work.
I tried the IAM simulator to see if the S3 put command would work and it did.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I can do?

Comment: for root user default home directory is /root. Are you sure your ~/ represents /root ?

Comment: Yes, I am, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From [Configuring the AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html):

> The AWS CLI uses a provider chain to look for AWS credentials in a number of different places, including system or user environment variables and local AWS configuration files.
>
> The AWS CLI looks for credentials and configuration settings in the following order:
>
> 1. **Command Line Options** – region, output format and profile can be specified as command options to override default settings.
> 2. **Environment Variables** – `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, etc.
> 3. **The AWS credentials file** – located at `~/.aws/credentials` on Linux, macOS, or Unix, or at `C:\Users\USERNAME \.aws\credentials` on Windows. This file can contain multiple named profiles in addition to a default profile.
> 4. **The CLI configuration file** – typically located at `~/.aws/config` on Linux, macOS, or Unix, or at `C:\Users\USERNAME \.aws\config` on Windows. This file can contain a default profile, named profiles, and CLI specific configuration parameters for each.
> 5. **Instance profile credentials** – these credentials can be used on EC2 instances with an assigned instance role, and are delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service.

It is also possible that you have the `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` set, which overrides which credentials are used in the configuration file.

Comment: This command give the following:  (empty)
root@app-server-2:~# echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

and the printenv does not list either of those env vars

Comment: I also tried setting those env vars and they didn't work :(

Comment: Updated my answer with the correct Credentials Providers Chain. Check whether you have the `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` environment variable set, which would change the profile being used. It's also worth making sure you have the latest version of the AWS CLI on your system -- `pip install awscli --upgrade`