# Why do I have authority in AWS management console but not in AWS CLI for some operations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I have an AWS root account and I created a IAM user with `Administrator` policy attached. The problem is that when I make some operations like `aws ec2 create-key-pair` in the aws-cli, I got `UnauthorizedOperation` error. But if I sign into the management console using the same IAM user, I can create a key pair with no problem.

I double checked my access key id and secret access key is right. I even re-created these and configured in aws-cli to make sure I am using that user account with admin permissions. None of these worked

Is there any setting I'm not aware of that enables aws-cli access permissions?

=============== below is latest update ================

I checked my user info with `aws sts get-caller-identify`, and it shows my company's account id. I tried to run `aws configure` again and followed by `aws sts get-caller-identity`, it still shows that im using my company's account. How do I switch user from CLI?

Comment: call `aws sts get-caller-identity` from terminal and check whether the user name is the same as the one that you are using in management console

Comment: Please edit your question to show the policy assigned to the IAM User.

Comment: @MatusDubrava Thanks for your reply. I tried to call the command and I discovered that I'm using a user with same name under difference Account IDs. I'm sure that I am using the correct Access Key ID and Secret Access Key. How did that log me in under a different account?

Comment: IAM users are account specific. You can't use one IAM user across multiple accounts (not talking about cross account permissions) which means that you can log only into the account where the user was created. Are you sure that you are using correct user profile? Note that you can pass `--profile` flag to `aws configure` to create additional profiles but then you need to pass this `--profile` flag to every command otherwise default user will be used which may differ from the one that you actually want to use.

Comment: @MatusDubrava thanks for the explanation. I found that when I use `aws configure` to setup account info, it's showing me my personal account info. But immediately after that if I use `aws sts get-caller-identity`, my company's account info is displayed. I checked the credential file and it only has one [default] account. It looks like aws-cli is not reading credentials from ~/.aws/credentials at all. Is there any way to reset the configuration completely?

Comment: That doesn't make much of a sense. I would suggest to you to launch EC2 instance, use `aws configure` (just for testing purposes) on the instance and try whether the behavior changes or not before doing something more drastic.

Comment: @MatusDubrava I re-configured using `aws configure`, and tried to run `aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-2b3b6041 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --iam-instance-profile Name=ecsInstanceRole --key-name aws-patrick --security-group-ids sg-d7e7628b --user-data file://copy-ecs-config-to-s3` and it says that security group doesn't exist on VPC. I think that certainly means I'm performing this action using my company's account. I tried to reinstall aws-cli and re-configure, but the result is the same :(, I also checked my environment variables. Nothing suspicious there... this is so weird!

Answer (score 3):

In case this helps anyone, the issue for me was that my AWS account used MFA. I never considered you'd have to do this on the command-line too. Here is a guide from Amazon on the subject:

[How do I use an MFA token to authenticate access to my AWS resources through the AWS CLI?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/)

Answer (score 1):

This is an incredibly big pot hole to step into... but there is a precedence of where aws cli looks for credentials.

[IAM credentials not found on AWS CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541746/iam-credentials-not-found-on-aws-cli)

The answer of the question here explains it throughly.